# How can I combine these two SQL queries (Access/VBA)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am using two SQL queries in VBA that i believe they could be done in one, but I cant get it to work. I Want to turn the VBA portion into a Query outside of VBA, the VBA keeps breaking my file due to the amount of data it processes. (By break i mean it gives a message that says "this file is not a valid database" rendering the file corrupted). I search for that error but all i found was not related to breaking because of VBA code.

Anyways, here are the two queries ran with VBA.

```
SELECT ET.VerintEID AS EID, Sum(ET.ExceptMin)/60 AS Exeptions
FROM Tbl_VExceptTime AS ET
INNER JOIN Tbl_VCodes ON ET.Exception = Tbl_VCodes.Exception
WHERE (ET.ExceptDate Between #" & sDate & "# And #" & eDate & "#)
GROUP BY ET.VerintEID, Tbl_VCodes.IsApd
HAVING Tbl_VCodes.IsApd = ""OFF"";
```

I loop these results to update a table.

```
Do While Not .EOF
    SQL = "UPDATE Tbl_AttendanceByAgent SET EXC = " & recSet.Fields(1).Value & _
        " WHERE VerintID = '" & recSet.Fields(0).Value & "'"
    CurrentDb.Execute SQL
    .MoveNext
Loop
```

I know that i can save the results from the first query into a table and without looping I can update the main table with another SQL query, but I believe it can be done on a single SQL. I have tried using an UPDATE with a SELECT of the first query but it just errors out on me with an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this could be achieved in one single query as shown below

```
UPDATE Tbl_AttendanceByAgent 
SET Tbl_AttendanceByAgent.EXC = t2.Exeptions
from Tbl_AttendanceByAgent t1
inner join (
    SELECT ET.VerintEID AS EID, Sum(ET.ExceptMin)/60 AS Exeptions
    FROM Tbl_VExceptTime AS ET
    INNER JOIN Tbl_VCodes as TV ON ET.Exception = TV.Exception    
    WHERE (ET.ExceptDate Between #" & sDate & "# And #" & eDate & "#)
    GROUP BY ET.VerintEID, TV.IsApd
    HAVING Tbl_VCodes.IsApd = 'OFF'
) AS t2 on t2.EID = t1.VerintID
```

**Note:** I suppose you will replace sDate, eDate with values within your code

Comment: Thank you, I will be trying this tomorrow morning and report back.

Comment: I guess that this query will not execute because Access update statements require that the table being updated resolves to verifiable unique rows, but joining on an aggregate query likely will not produce such rows... especially since the query is grouped on values from two tables on columns which are not in the join expression and likely don't have suitable indexes.  I'm not meaning to be a naysayer, but I might not be able to return to this question before you all test it.  I hope you prove me wrong, but now you have an idea why if it doesn't work.

Comment: This is a standard SQL (ANSI SQL supported) for the requirement. I can't tell much, if due to any deficiencies within Access, this doesn't run.
@CPerkins - Note that aggregation is happening on joining of two different tables, not the table that is being updated. Also, think of the select part to inner join as inline view. DB engines execute that part first and use the result of that in update.

Comment: @Gro  I am specifically addressing behavior in Access.  Although other DBMS have smart enough engines to properly deduce valid update code in these cases, Access is very particular on what it determines is updatable.  Access SQL is not necessarily ANSI SQL.

Comment: @Gro I understand very well the query structure and what it means, but I did overlook that the HAVING condition paired with the GROUP BY will indeed produce unique `EID` values.  However, from experience, Access looses the definition of such uniqueness (if defined in an index, for instance) in an aggregate expression even though it can be deduced logically.  There is no way to direct Access to "reindex" such intermediate results to use for the subsequent join to the updated table.  Access therefore assumes the join is not unique and will refuse to update.

Comment: @Gro... but your expression might work in Access if you combine my suggested edit of the nested query, so that it only groups on EID.  Then Access may preserve its uniqueness and allow the update based on the join.  In other words, change inner query to `AND Tbl_VCodes.IsApd = 'OFF' GROUP BY ET.VerintEID;`

Comment: I want to thank you both, I was able to create the single query by using both of the answers here. I also was able to stop the database from breaking apart with VBA by using C Perkins answer. I am unsure of which answer to mark as the correct one since both have helped me tremendously. I will mark one by the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

This question is an answer to the described errors and the given code, although it technically does not answer the request for a single SQL statement.  I started adding a comment, but that's just too tedious when this answer box allows everything to be expressed efficiently at once.

First of all, referring to `CurrentDb` is actually NOT a basic reference to a single object instance.  Rather it is more like a function call that generates a new, unique "clone" of the underlying database object.  Calling it over and over again is known to produce memory leaks, and at the least is very inefficient.  See [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.currentdb) for details.

Although the given code is short, it's not sweet.  Not only is it repeatedly creating new database objects, it is repeatedly executing an SQL statement to update what I assume is a single row each time.  That also entails regenerating the SQL string each time.

Even if executing the SQL statement repeatedly was an efficient option, there are better ways to do that, like creating a temporary (in-memory) QueryDef object with parameters.  Each loop iteration then just resets the parameters and executes the same prepared SQL statement.

But in this case, it may actually be more efficient to load the table being updated into a DAO.Recordset, then use the in-memory Recordset to search for a match, then use the recordset to update the row.

I suspect that addressing a couple of those issues would make your VBA code viable.

```
Dim db as Database
Set db = CurrentDb 'Get just a single instance and reuse

Dim qry as QueryDef
SQL = "PARAMETERS pEXC Text ( 255 ), pID Long; " & _
    " UPDATE Tbl_AttendanceByAgent SET EXC = pEXC " & _
    " WHERE VerintID = pID"
set qry = db.CreateQueryDef("", SQL)

'With recSet '???
Do While Not .EOF
    qry.Parameters("pEXC") = recSet.Fields(1).Value
    qry.Parameters("pID") = recSet.Fields(0).Value
    qry.Execute
   .MoveNext
Loop
'End With recSet '???

'OR an alternative

Dim recUpdate As DAO.Recordset2
Set recUpdate = db.OpenRecordset("Tbl_AttendanceByAgent", DB_OPEN_TABLE)

Do While Not .EOF
    recUpdate.FindFirst "VerintID = " & recSet.Fields(0).Value
    If Not recUpdate.NoMatch Then
      recUpdate.Edit
      recUpdate.Fields("EXC") = recSet.Fields(1).Value
      recUpdate.Update
    End If
   .MoveNext
Loop
```

---

I realized in commenting on Gro's answer, that the original query's aggregate clauses will produce unique values on EID, but it then becomes obvious that there is no need to group on (and sum) values which do not have `Tbl_VCodes.IsApd = 'OFF'`.  The query would be more efficient like

```
SELECT ET.VerintEID AS EID, Sum(ET.ExceptMin)/60 AS Exeptions
FROM Tbl_VExceptTime AS ET
   INNER JOIN Tbl_VCodes ON ET.Exception = Tbl_VCodes.Exception
WHERE (ET.ExceptDate Between #" & sDate & "# And #" & eDate & "#)
   AND Tbl_VCodes.IsApd = 'OFF'
GROUP BY ET.VerintEID;
```

BTW, you could consider implementing the same temporary QueryDef pattern as I showed above, then you'd change the first WHERE expression to something like

```
PARAMETERS PsDate DateTime, PeDate DateTime;
...
WHERE (ET.ExceptDate Between [PsDate] And [PeDate])
...
```

Comment: The given code is short but the entire function is actually using 'CurrentDb' a lot more, your answer definitely makes sense as to why it breaks the file. Will go through my code and reduce the usage of 'CurrentDb' to a single instance and with both answers given I'm sure I will find the single query i'm looking for. Will report back once I start working with it.